# unselect sprite clicking somewhere else on stage or other movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3

In my scenario I have a sprite "imgSprite" with dynamically loaded image. I have drawn a small box near bottom left corner inside this sprite named "rectangle". The imageSprite is also drag/drop able. When I click on the image I set it to show rectangle but I can not figure out how to hide it clicking somewhere outside imgSpirte.

```
var imgSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
imgSprite.addChild(image);
MovieClip(root).addChild(imgSprite);

/* DELETE BUTTON */
var rectangle:Sprite = new Sprite();
rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20,20);
rectangle.graphics.endFill();
rectangle.y=imgSprite.y+imgSprite.height;
rectangle.x=imgSprite.x-20;
imgSprite.addChild(rectangle);

rectangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {
    rectangle.parent.parent.removeChild(imgSprite);
});

imgSprite.addEventListener("mouseDown", function() {
    imgSprite.startDrag();
    rectangle.visible = true;
});

stage.addEventListener("mouseUp", function() {
    imgSprite.stopDrag();
});

/*
imgSprite.addEventListener("mouseOut", function() {
    var timer = setInterval(deSelect,3000);
    function deSelect(){
      rectangle.visible = false;
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
});
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a temporary listener for stage. Say, like this:

```
if (rectangle) rectangle.visible=false; // or it won't trigger
imgSprite.addEventListener("mouseDown",onMouseDown);
function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (rectangle) if (!rectangle.visible) 
        stage.addEventListener("mouseDown",removeRectangle);
    imgSprite.startDrag();
    rectangle.visible=true;
    e.stopPropagation(); // this is needed to not get the rectangle removed as soon as you click on imgSprite
}
function removeRectangle(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (rectangle) rectangle.visible=false;
    stage.removeEventListener("mouseDown",removeRectangle);
}
```

It works like this: As soon as you click on the `imgSprite`, a listener gets assigned to stage and the rectangle is made visible. If you click on `imgSprite` again, the rectangle is already visible, so no extra listeners are added. Also `e.stopPropagation()` prevents an existing listener to get triggered and get the rectangle hidden. And as soon as you click elsewhere but on `imgSprite`, the listener gets triggered, removes itself from stage, and hides `rectangle`.

Comment: tried but it didn't work. i managed it to work somehow this way http://pastebin.com/LJHrjbk2 now the only problem is it deselects (hide rec/del button) when state is selected on clicking selected movieclip.

Comment: use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` in anonymous function that creates the listener on stage. Also I don't understand why does the `mouseUp` listener is assigned to stage, not to `mc`? If you'd assign it to `mc`, it should help you tracking if you've clicked the mc or outside of mc.